# How can I update an Exchange Server Monitoring Override?

Tags: exchange-2013

Assume you have an Exchange 2013 server with existing Server Monitoring Overrides which you can get by running on the Exchange Shell:

```
Get-ServerMonitoringOverride -Server servername | ft -auto
```

and the output shows something like:

```
Identity                                        ItemType PropertyName        PropertyValue
--------                                        -------- ------------        -------------
MailboxSpace\StorageLogicalDriveSpaceMonitor\G: Monitor  MonitoringThreshold 50000
MailboxSpace\StorageLogicalDriveSpaceMonitor\H: Monitor  MonitoringThreshold 50000
MailboxSpace\StorageLogicalDriveSpaceMonitor\L: Monitor  MonitoringThreshold 25000
```

In the above example there are server overrides to prevent the default Exchange monitoring to rise an alert when a drive drops below the default 100GB limit.

And let's say that you want to change an existing override (for example the existing one has expired, or you want to change the PropertyValue of MonitoringThreshold to be 10000 instead).

How would you modify an existing ServerMonitorOverride in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out (unless I'm really missing it), that the only want to modify existing Exchange monitoring overrides is to remove them and recreate them.  This INCLUDES setting new durations for expiration on them if they are expired.

An example is below (based on the example output in the question):

```
Remove-ServerMonitoringOverride -server MAILSERVER -Identity MailboxSpace\StorageLogicalDriveSpaceMonitor\G: -ItemType Monitor -PropertyName MonitoringThreshold
```

Then to add it back in with a new expiration date one year from today's date:

```
Add-ServerMonitoringOverride -server MAILSERVER -Identity MailboxSpace\StorageLogicalDriveSpaceMonitor\G: -ItemType Monitor -PropertyName MonitoringThreshold -PropertyValue 50000 -Duration 365
```

You can then see the new expiration date for that monitor by running:

```
Get-ServerMonitoringOverride -server MAILSERVER | fl
```